# HDf5DotNet : File close not sync?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, synchronization, hdf5

### Description

We are currently writing tests against our hdf5 abstraction layer.

We have a test that ensure that dataset type change doesn't affect our abstraction layer. To test this, we create a new hdf5 file each time we want to test a dataset type change.
After each operation (read/write) the hdf5 file is closed.

The problem is that the modification in the hdf5 file don't seems to be **written synchronously** when we call **H5F.Close()**.

When our test is **executed in debug** (using step by step debugger) the test is **working fine**.

When executed in **release**, the **test is broken**, and our abstraction layer read a dataset value that is the value of the dataset **before the last modification** (from former dataset type).

We also found that if the test is executed with a Thread.Sleep(1000) between I/O operations, the test in release mode is **executed properly**.

### Questions

- Do you have any idea what can be **wrong/ forgotten** when **calling** the **HDF5 library** ?
- Is there a way in the HDF5DotNEt to **get the number of active/opened objects** (dataset/group etc ...) from a file, as **H5Fget_obj_count** is not implemented in the HDF5DotNet library.

### EDIT

**oct. 4th 2017**

- I used the HDF5DotNet sources to build my own version including the **H5Fget_obj_count** function. All objects are closed when closing the file.
- Also implemented the function **H5Pset_fclose_degree** to force close degree to **H5F_CLOSE_STRONG**, no changes.
- hdf5 file can be open with writes rights right after using H5F.Close()

### Tested/Implemented solutions

- Force **H5F.Flush** before closing file, no effect
- Checking that every single object form the HDF5 library has been **closed properly** including:

  - H5DataSetId
  - H5FileId
  - H5GroupId
  - H5AttributeId
  - H5DataTypeId
  - H5DataSpaceId
  - H5PropertyListId
- Tried to find if there is a memory leak from the C++ HDF5 library (errors always come from the same assert and read values are coherent with the HDF5 file content)

### Env

- Visual studio 2017
- HDF5DotNet.x64 v1.8.9
- NUNit v3.6.1
- NUnit3TestAdapter v3.7.0

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for giving your time.

Comment: Are different processes reading the file or different threads?

Comment: No, the file is only used by the test and the test is single threaded.

Comment: Does the test involve one process writing to the file and another reading it?

Comment: No, there is only one process

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question :

The **HDF5 library is working fine** and the error is coming from one of **our** object.

During tests I am updating an object that is cached. The cache last modification time tracker resolution is the second, way to imprecise when doing intensive unit testing. As this object define the model inside our HDF5 file, it causes to read the former defined type, not the expected data type.

Thanks for your time !